# .libPaths() not changing

Tags: r, bash

I have set `R_LIBS` in my `.bash_profile` to

```
export R_LIBS=/lib/R-3.3.0
```

and when I `echo $R_LIBS`, it returns `/lib/R-3.3.0` but, when I start R and type `.libPaths()` I get `/Software/R`.

What is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "/lib/R-3.3.0") )`

Comment: What OS?  Does `/lib/R-3.3.0` exist?

Comment: @TomNash that doesn't change it permanently.

Comment: @Bhas yes, it does and CentOS 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `R_LIBS_USER`:

```
$ Rscript -e 'print(.libPaths())'
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"   
[3]            "/usr/lib/R/library"           
$ R_LIBS_USER="/tmp" Rscript -e 'print(.libPaths())'
[1]                    "/tmp"  "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" 
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"             "/usr/lib/R/library" 
$
```

We see that adding one value to `R_LIBS_USER` adds a fourth directory
to the three I get by default on my system.